# Compilation from source: LESS file is empty:

Tags: module, extensions, magento-upgrade, swatches, version

I have upgraded my magento version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6-p3 and in exceptions.log file i am  continuously getting one error i.e

```
main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException: Compilation from source: LESS file is empty: frontend/new/latest/en_US/Magento_Swatches/css/swatches.less in /chroot/home/a/com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php:99
```

If anyone have any solution. Please help!

Comment: Hi @Tisha, It seems like the issue is in the child theme. Can you check/verify the child theme.xml file has the correct parent theme name?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem lies with your child theme, which is causing Magento to be unable to inherit the swatches.less CSS.

**Here is a link to a similar issue:**

[Compilation from source: LESS file is empty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351140/compilation-from-source-less-file-is-empty)

Please take a look at the above link, as the solutions provided there may resolve your problem.

Comment: Checked the link and tried the solution but still issue persists

Comment: Have you overridden any Swatch module related files in your theme? If possible, could you please share your theme's XML file.